# Access variable inside of a link inside of highcharts tooltip

Tags: html, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am adding a link to my highcharts tooltip and I need the variable {point.key} to be added inside the link but I am unable to access it. When I take it out of the  tag I can access it just fine.

Line of code in question:

```
`<a href="/events/discover?${chart.aggregation}={point.key}"/>View</a>`,
```

Entire code snippet:

```
options.series = allSeriesState.map((seriesState) => {
            return {
                seriesId: seriesState.seriesId,
                name: seriesState.name,
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: `<table><tr><th>${chart.xTitle}: {point.key:%Y-%m-%d}</th></tr>`,
                    pointFormat:
                        `<tr><td><b>{point.y} </b><span style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}</span> Events</td></tr>` +
                        `<tr><td><a href="/admin/portfolio/miniApp/events/discover?event_type={series.name}&index=${seriesState.index}&timeFrame=${chart.timeFrame}&${chart.aggregation}={point.key}"/>View in Discover</a></td></tr>`,
                    footerFormat: '</table>'},
                type: seriesState.type,
                color: seriesState.color,
                data: seriesState.color && seriesState.type ? allSeriesData?.[seriesState.seriesId] || [] : []
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pointFormat` doesn't support more than one nesting level. Use `pointFormatter` function which has more flexibility.

```
pointFormatter() {
  let point = this;
  return `<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${point.category}" target="_blank">${point.category}</a>`
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oqvh8yx1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to add attributes from the point was to create a custom tooltip component like so:

```
            tooltip: {
                formatter() {
                    return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomTooltip {...this} chart={chart} />);
                },
```

Component:

```
import React, {ReactElement} from "react";
import {capitalizeFirstLetter} from "../../../../components/Defaults";


export default function CustomTooltip(props: any): ReactElement {
    console.log(props)
    let title
    let xAxis = JSON.stringify(props.x)
    let agg
    if(props.chart.panelType === "aggs_chart"){
        title = props.chart.xTitle
        agg = '&' + props.series.userOptions.aggregation + '=' + props.point.category
    } else {
        title = capitalizeFirstLetter(props.chart.timeInterval) + " " + "of"
        agg = ''
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h4><b>{title}:</b> {xAxis}</h4>
            <h4><b>{props.y} </b><span style={{color: props.color}}>{props.series.userOptions.name}</span><b> Events</b></h4>
            <h4><a href={'/admin/portfolio/miniApp/events/discover?event_type=' + props.series.userOptions.name + '&index=' + props.series.userOptions.index + '&timeFrame=' + props.chart.timeFrame + agg}>View in Discover</a></h4>
        </div>
    );
};
```